Expectation of Solution to SDE, logarithmic extension of Vasicek
I have the solution to the following model $$dr(t)=r(t)(\eta-a\log r(t))dt+\sigma r(t)dW(t)$$ which, through the Vasicek model and a change of variable, I found to be $$r(t)=\exp[Y(0)e^{-at}+\frac{\eta-\sigma^2/2}{2}(1-e^{-at})+\sigma e^{-at}\int_0^te^{at}dW(s)]$$
I want to compute the expectation of the solution above, but am unsure of how to treat the stochastic integral at the end. If someone could help me out it'd be greatly appreciated.

Is the integral $\int_{0}^{t} e^{as},dW(s)$ or $\int_{0}^{t}e^{at}dW(s)$? In either case, that stochastic integral will be a Gaussian variate.

$r(t)$ is of the form
$$\exp\bigg(g(t)+\sigma e^{-at}\int_{0}^{t}e^{as}dW(s)\bigg)$$
Now note that $e^{as}$ is a deterministic function in $s$ and hence $\int_{0}^{t}e^{as}dW_{s}$ is a Gaussian variate with mean $0$ (As it's a martingale) and variance given by Ito's Isometry,
$$Var(\int_{0}^{t}e^{as}dW(s))=\mathbb{E}(\int_{0}^{t}e^{2as}\,ds)=\frac{e^{2at}-1}{2a}$$
Thus, you are looking at $$\exp(g(t))\cdot\mathbb{E}\bigg(\exp\bigg(\sigma e^{-at} \cdot \mathscr{N}(0,\frac{e^{2at}-1}{2a}\bigg)\bigg)$$ which you can now compute by looking at the Moment Generating Function of a Gaussian variate.
Note:- The stochastic integral $\int_{0}^{t}f(t)dW_{t}$ of a deterministic function $f(t)$ which is $L^{2}[0,t]$ is a Gaussian variate because it is the $L^{2}$-limit of linear combinations of Gaussian variates. A proof can be found here.

Thanks, I was missing the result of the Ito Integral being a Gaussian variate

You will need the generating function of a standard Gaussian:
$$
\langle e^{tX}\rangle = e^{t^2/2}
$$
This generalises to independent standard gaussians:
$$
\left\langle \exp\left(\sum t_iX_i\right)\right\rangle = \exp\left(\frac12\sum t_i^2\right)
$$
In the continuous limit, seeing $\Delta W = \sqrt{\Delta t}X$ with $X$ a standard normal:
$$
\left\langle \exp\left(\int_0^tf(t)dW\right)\right\rangle = \exp\left(\frac12\int_0^T f(t)^2dt\right)
$$
so applied to your problem:
$$
\langle r\rangle \propto \exp\left(\frac{\sigma^2e^{-2at}}2\int_0^t e^{2as}ds\right)
$$
